# File import and object sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The dir tree looks like this:

```
Dir/
    Subdir/
           File1.py
           File2.py
           File3.py
           Result.py
```

File1.py

```
ObjA=aFunction(aNum)
ObjB=bFunction(aNum)
```

File2.py

```
ObjA=aFunction(aNum)
ObjB=bFunction(aNum)
```

File3.py

```
ObjA=aFunction(aNum)
ObjB=aFunction(aNum)
```

I want to sum the objects as an obj in the result.py file

Result.py

```
from subdir import file1,file2,file3

A=sum([file1.ObjA,file2.ObjA,file3.ObjA])
B=sum([file1.ObjB,file2.ObjB,file3.ObjB])
```

Is there a way to automate this method whereby I specify which obj I want to call without manually typing up the list

I.e

```
from subdir import files

Obj='ObjA'
A=sum(files.Obj)

Obj='ObjB'
B=sum(files.Obj)
```

So far, I have made attempts by creating a list of files in the subdir.
Trying to split the path of the list into filename
Concat the file name with the object name
Appended the concatenation to a new list, which I want to sum.
But the new list is a list of strings that can't be called to reference for use in the sum function.

Example.py

```
import os
Listing=[]
for file in os.listdir(subdir):
     Listing.append(file)

VariableAdd=[]
for file in listing:
    AFile=file.split(".")[0] 
    aFileObj=concat(aFile,".",'ObjA')
    VariableAdd.append(aFile)
```

I would like to now sum the variables held in thr variableAdd list.

Comment: Why are your keywords capitalized? Are you writing this on mobile? This isn't valid Python.

Comment: Do you mean words such as 'for' or 'from'?  I assumed with the level of intelligence I had come see from this site there would of been a level intuition with interpretation, but if my assumption was wrong, please confirm and I will make the necessary changes.  Because yes, a mobile, my setup is currently very nomadic. I was hoping the tools I develop with this language might assist in creating a more secure and permanent environment

Comment: Look up something like "dynamically loading arbitrary python modules", and use `getattr` on the returned objects.